# Find integers $b, c $ so that $3b\equiv3c\pmod{12}$, but $b \not\equiv c\pmod{12}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$3b\equiv{3c}\quad(\text{mod }12),$$
but
$$b\not\equiv{c}\quad(\text{mod }12).$$

I am not sure how to approach this problem, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about investigating all values of $3b$ modulo $12$?

Comment: Find some small $\,b \ne c\,$ such that $\,3(b-c) \equiv 0 \pmod{12}\,$.

Answer (score 4):

$3b\equiv 3c\pmod{12}$ means $3b=3c+12k$ for *k* integer, and $b\not\equiv c\pmod{12}$ is saying $b\ne c+12k$'. Solve these inequalities: $0\ne 0+12k'-4k$, i.e., $4k\ne 12k'$, which again means $k\ne 3k'$. In summary, we have $b=c+4k$ for any *c*, *k*, with *k* is not multiple of 3.

Comment: Yes. as edited. Thank you. I didn't notice the second mod at the first place.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Edited, and added a little bit of details in solving the inequalities.

Comment: One editing tip:  If you type `$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$`, you will obtain $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$.

Comment: Thank you, but how to say "not equiv"?

Comment: You can obtain $\not\equiv$ by typing `$\not\equiv$`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83828/discussion-between-miles-zhou-and-n-f-taussig).

Answer (score 1):

$3 \times 4 = 0 = 3 \times 8 \pmod{12}$ but $4 \neq 8 \pmod{12}$.

We abuse that $3|12$, or more generally that $3$ and $12$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Approach it by doing it.

Figure out what $3*a\mod 12$ is for $a=0...11$ and see if any of them are the same for different $a $s.

Doesn't take long to notice $3*0\equiv 3*4\mod 12$.

In fact for $a=0...11$ the $3a\equiv :$  $0,3,6,9,0,3,6,9,0,3,6,9$

So $0\equiv 3*0\equiv 3*4\equiv 3*8 \mod 12$

And $3\equiv 3*1\equiv 3*5\equiv 2*9\mod 12$

$6\equiv 3*2\equiv 3*6\equiv ... etc.$
Etc, are lots of counter examples.